# NUnit test project can't load assembly for System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nunit

I have an NUnit test project dedicated for unit testing which has a Target Framework of .Net Core 2.1. This test project has references of two other Projects one of which is a *Windows Form* based application and the other is a *Class Library* based application for database interactions. Both of these projects has a target framework of .Net Framework 4.6.1

I am writing a test for testing a method of the *Class Library* based application to test the output of the method. But it's showing the following error,

**'System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'**

I have tried the following fixes and none of them worked.

- Removing the project references and adding them again
- Changing build platform target from AnyCPU to X86 and x64
- Adding **dependant assemblies** tag inside a .config file. (Interesting things is .NET Core 2.1 doesn't provide with a .config file)

*This is the test class (Test_DataClasses.cs)*,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using SharedDataClasses;
using MantechAutomationControl;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MAC_Testing
{
[TestFixture]
class Test_DataClasses
{
    #region Tests
    [Test]
    public void t_m_initializeDatabase()
    {
        //Assign
        string v_dbLocation = Path.Combine("M:\\For_Jabed\\MAC\\MAC\\MantechAutomationControl\\bin\\Debug\\", "DB.sqlite");
        //Act
        DataClasses_v2.m_initializeDatabase();
        //Assert
        Assert.That(new FileInfo(v_dbLocation), Does.Exist);
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

*And this is the method the above test is trying to validate*,

```
public static class DataClasses_v2
{
    #region Variables 
    #endregion
    #region Methods
    public static void  m_initializeDatabase()
    {
        string v_executableLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string v_dbLocation = Path.Combine(v_executableLocation, "DB.sqlite");
        if (!File.Exists(v_dbLocation))
        {
            DialogResult o_createDBFileDialogBox = MessageBox.Show("Could not find the database in the expected location:\n" + v_dbLocation + "\n\nWould you like to create a new blank database file?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (o_createDBFileDialogBox == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(v_dbLocation);
                using (SQLiteConnection o_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"DataSource=" + v_dbLocation + ";Version=3;"))
                {
                    o_dbConnection.Open();
                }
            }
            else
                return;
        }
    }
```

I don't really understand whats going on here. Although point to be noted I actually was working towards to use *Nunit Form* dll to work with Forms (DialogBox) as the method to be tested had a DialogBox to work with.

In the test project there is another class and the tests written inside those class works fine for the Same target 'Class Library' based project to validate a different function.

Hopefully someone will be able to explain whats going on here.

Comment: "_unit testing which has a Target Framework of **.Net Core 2.1**_" vs. "_Both of these projects has a target framework of **.Net Framework 4.6.1**_" (emphasis mine). Decide and chose one target framework... (guess you'll have to go with .NET Framework, as with regard to .NET Core, WindowsForms will only be available since .NET Core 3.0)

Comment: Even if I try Using Nunit forms it specifically says package mismatch as Nunit forms works only with .Net framework but not .Net Core. I believe separation of codebase logic is the only way left here to really test form based solution. But thanks for your input.