# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly' on a local machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am implementing unit tests on a project that I joined recently and came across a puzzling error. I have this class `LoggerSettingsManager` with various functions that I am testing. When calling certain functions everything works fine. But when calling the same class but different functions I receive the following error (The error has an inner code _COMPlusExceptionCode -532462766):

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

These are the libraries that `LoggerSettingsManager` requires:

Many function seems to be doing just fine. It seems to only happen if the function references a `MessageBox` (part of `System.Windows.Forms`), even if this line of code is never actually executed.

Problems arise when I call for example the following function. What slightly confuses me however, is that I can't even step into the function before causing the error, as if the content of the function is not the issue but some library associated with the class.

```
public void UpdateLoggerSettings(string measurementType)
{
    ...

    try
    {
        _deviceSettings.GetLoggerSettings(LoggerSettings);

        if (LoggerSettings.DataIsValid)
            _deviceSettingsWin.UpdateWindowParameter();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Requesting Data Logger Settings: Packet contained invalid time stamps\n\n" +
            ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

These are the `usings` in `LoggerSettingsManager`:

```
using ExpoMRF4Utility.ExpomRF4; // internal company library
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Do I somehow need to "freshly install" `System.Windows.Forms`? I have seen other articles on this error, but it seems like many issues are server-client related (which mine is definitely *not*) or specific in another way. Help appreciated.

**Edit**: removing and adding the reference did not solve the issue ..

**Edit 2**: adding minimal reproducible files on pastebin: [LoggerSettingsManager](https://pastebin.com/xCNeRdLX), [LoggerSettingsManager_Tests](https://pastebin.com/bfwX5xrr)

Comment: You can't step into the function because, the first time `UpdateLoggerSettings` is about to be called, the JIT compiler attempts to compile the function. It fails because of MessageBox (in System.Windows.Forms, which it apparently cannot find) and throws the exception you see.

It might help to include a minimal reproducible example, but you may also want to check which .NET platform your projects are targeting. This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401372/nunit-test-project-cant-load-assembly-for-system-windows-forms looks similar.

Comment: Have you looked at the references that your project is using? Do any of them have a little yellow triangle? If so, I would delete and then re-add them back.

Comment: Have you added the reference to you test project or just to the project under test?

Comment: @pmcoltrane
This is what I understood myself, that the compiler only checks the code required in that specific function and throws if that can't be loaded.
I added links to two pastebin files with minimum reproducible files.

Comment: @David.Warwick
On the same branch I had a few references with a little yellow triangle. But they had duplicates with the same name, so I removed them. I removed the duplicates and re-added them now, but it doesn't seem to change much.

Comment: @bschellekens This is an interesting question. I created a "xUnit Test Project" in my solution. In the Solution Explorer this testing project does not show any "References", only "Dependencies". I can't add System.Windows.Forms as a reference. I did however add my project under test as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have been able to solve the issue by creating a different testing project. In the image below there are the options that Visual Studio offers for creating a Test Project. Previously I chose a `xUnit Test Project` which turns out to only run .NET Core and it was impossible to reference the same version of .NET as the project under test, or references to the "missing" library `System.Windows.Forms`.

Now I created a `Unit Test Project (.NET Framework)`, while adding xUnit and removing MSTest. This seems to have done the trick. I hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.

[image: Visual Studio prompt for creating a Test Project]

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! I couldn't do it immediately but now it works. Thanks for pointing it out :)